# perl6 function to get links available only when hover

Tags: html, hyperlink, hover, raku

Does perl6 have functions to obtain links that are only available when mouse hovers of clicks buttons?

For instance, on some websites, if you look at the page source from Firefox, you will not see the links. But if you hover the mouse, you will see the links.

Does Perl6 have functions to extract those links, or I am stuck with JavaScript?

Comment: This is a non-trivial process in JS (which is far more tightly integrated with the DOM / CSS) because of the multitude of ways that a hover could cause a link to appear.  If it's through pure CSS via, say, an `:after`, it could probably be done more or less easily through P6, but if it's being generated on the fly in JavaScript, it's probably easiest to do that, rather than having to constantly bridge back and forth between the two (although that is possible).

Comment: Got it !! Thank you very much guifa !!! I will use JavaScript for this part for now. Thanks.